# Delete arguments from array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

There is table w/ colum called Cars in this colum I have array [Audi, BMW, Toyota, ..., VW]

And I want update this table and set Cars without few elements from this array (Toyota,..., BMW)

How can I get it, I want put another array and delete elements that matched

Comment: please rephrase , also give sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest the array, filter, and reaggregate:

```
select t.*,
       (select array_agg(car)
        from unnest(t.cars) car
        where car not in ( . . . )
       ) new_cars
from t;
```

If you want to keep the original ordering:

```
select t.*,
       (select array_agg(u.car order by n)
        from unnest(t.cars) with ordinality u(car, n)
        where u.car not in ( . . . )
       ) new_cars
from t
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. but I had another task, I wanted update table and final result looks like


`update table
set "cars" = result.new_cars
from (
select t.*,
       (select array_agg(car)
        from unnest(table.cars) car
        where car not in (...)
       ) new_cars
from t 
) as result
where result.id = cars.id`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I Can help using pandas in python. Assuming, you'd want to delete all the rows having the elements you'd like to delete. Lets say df is your dataframe, then,

```
import pandas as pd

vals_to_delete = df.loc[(df['cars']== 'Audi') | (df['cars']== 'VW')]

df = df.drop(vals_to_delete)
```

or you could also do

```
df1 = df.loc'[(df['cars']!= 'Audi') | (df['cars']!= 'VW')]
```

In sql, you could use

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE Cars in ('Audi','VW);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `array_remove` several times:

```
SELECT array_remove(
          array_remove(
             ARRAY['Audi', 'BMW', 'Toyota', 'Opel', 'VW'],
             'Audi'
          ),
          'BMW'
       );

   array_remove   
------------------
 {Toyota,Opel,VW}
(1 row)
```